# Ruby Mongoid::Errors::InvalidField

Tags: ruby, mongoid

```
class MyModule::MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :field1, :type=>Integer
  ...
  field :fieldn, :type=>Integer
  field :deleted, :type=>Boolean

  store_in session: 'mydb', collection: 'mycollection'
end
```

These code threw `Mongoid::Errors::InvalidField` when came to `:deleted` definition. If I remove this line, it works well.

```
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.0/lib/mongoid/fields/validators/macro.rb:56:in `block in validate_name':  (Mongoid::Errors::InvalidField)`
```

As http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Errors/InvalidField says,

> This error is raised when trying to create a field that conflicts with
>   an already defined method.

How can I use this conflicted name?

Answer (score -1):

When I try to add a `deleted` field, Mongoid 4.0.2 says:

```
Problem:
  Defining a field named 'deleted?' is not allowed.
Summary:
  Defining this field would override the method 'deleted?', which would cause issues with expectations around the original method and cause extremely hard to debug issues. The original method was defined in:
  ...
```

When you say:

```
field :f
```

Mongoid creates *three* methods for that field: `f` (getter), `f=` (setter), and `f?` (is `f` truthy AFAIK). The last one is causing your problem because Mongoid has its own `deleted?` method.

Your best bet would be to use a different name for that field, `field :is_deleted` perhaps.

If you can't do that (i.e. you're attaching Mongoid to a predefined collection), then you could use dynamic attributes:

```
class MyModule::MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :field1, :type=>Integer
  ...
  field :fieldn, :type=>Integer
  # Don't define the field here

  store_in session: 'mydb', collection: 'mycollection'
end
```

and then you'd access it use Mongoid's `[]` and `[]=` methods:

```
d = MyModule::MyModel.new
d[:deleted] = true

d = MyModule::MyModel.find(id)
puts d[:deleted]
puts d.attributes['deleted']
```

You could also add your own `is_deleted` and `is_deleted=` methods that would use `[]` and `[]=` to update the underlying attribute.